# Not able to call the function within the index.php from the controller

Tags: php, .htaccess, model-view-controller

So I'm learning PHP and have started with something very basic.

I am trying to call a function from a file within my controller folder however it will not work.

I have been successfully able to echo out anything I type into the URL bar, but it just wont print out the message in my other index.php file as a part of the controller but of course will continue to echo any message input of the URL. Am I missing something?

So here's what I have sitting outside my MVC folders which is an index.php file:

```
<?php

$url = $_GET['url'];

echo $url;

require 'controllers/' . $url . '.php';
$controller = new $url;
?>
```

And here is what I have in my index.php file within my controllers folder that I am trying to call:

```
<?php

class Index {

  function __construct(){
    echo 'We are in index';
  }
}

?>
```

My .htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Are you using the correct case? Function names are case sensitive. Also linux is case sensitive so if you have the class Index in index.php it will fail.

Comment: Sorry what do mean you mean by that? And yes I'm using Linux.

Comment: your htaccess file says, "If trying to access domain.com/Foo turn it into domain.com/index.php?url=Foo on the server" well urls are case insensitive, but linux file system is not (what your php script is accessing) so Index and index are different places on the file system. Also the functions/classes are case sensitive so if you named the file index.php and put Index class in it your script would try to access either the wrong file (if you tryed Index) or the wrong class (if you tried index)

Answer (score 0):

change your `controller/index.php` to `controller/Index.php` if you're on linux and then try to access index with all lower case.

Comment: I have tried both of the suggestions you have made. But I am still experiencing the same issue.

Comment: There's no error at all, it just doesn't display what I have written in the index.php file through the class Index.

Comment: if you add an echo before the class deceleration in your controllers/index.php does it output anything?

Comment: I have just tried that and the result remains the same. Just nothing.

Comment: It's as if the index.php just can't be accessed at all. It only recognises what is in the immediate file which is the index.php file outside of my MVC.

Comment: You're using require, if the file was not found php would throw a E_COMPILE_ERROR exception.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I found out that my error was due to how I had labeled the name after require. I changed it from 'controllers/' to '../controllers/' which allowed me to see the message.